# 'int' object is not subscriptableの解消方法

Tags: python, python3

任意のSignal-to-Noise比の音声波形をPythonで作ろう！
https://engineering.linecorp.com/ja/blog/voice-waveform-arbitrary-signal-to-noise-ratio-python/

こちらのプログラムを実行した所、以下のメッセージが出ました。
これの解決方法を教えていただきたいです。

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-f3a553f9c2cc> in <module>
     24 
     25 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 26     args = get_args()
     27 
     28     clean_file = args.clean_file

<ipython-input-3-f3a553f9c2cc> in get_args()
     19     parser.add_argument('--output_noise_file', type=str, default='')
     20     parser.add_argument('--output_noisy_file', type=str, default='')
---> 21     parser.add_argument(snr, type=float)
     22     args = parser.parse_args()
     23     return args

~\anaconda3\lib\argparse.py in add_argument(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1345         # argument
   1346         chars = self.prefix_chars
-> 1347         if not args or len(args) == 1 and args[0][0] not in chars:
   1348             if args and 'dest' in kwargs:
   1349                 raise ValueError('dest supplied twice for positional argument')

TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

#### 該当のソースコード

```py
import argparse
import array
import math
import numpy as np
import random
import wave

clean_file = 音声ファイル
noise_file = ノイズファイル

snr = 20


def get_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(clean_file, type=str)
    parser.add_argument(noise_file, type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--output_clean_file', type=str, default='')
    parser.add_argument('--output_noise_file', type=str, default='')
    parser.add_argument('--output_noisy_file', type=str, default='')
    parser.add_argument(snr, type=float)
    args = parser.parse_args()
    return args
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = get_args()

    clean_file = args.clean_file
    noise_file = args.noise_file
    snr = args.snr

    clean_wav = wave.open(clean_file, "r")
    noise_wav = wave.open(noise_file, "r")
```

#### 試したこと

該当サイトに記されているrequired=True等、一部プログラムが異なっていますが、
パスの指定のために外しただけなので特に問題ありません。

Comment: `parser.add_argument(snr, type=float)` の部分ですが、参考にしている記事では `parser.add_argument('--snr', type=float, default='', required=True)` となっています。記事の通りにすると動作しました。

Comment: stn.py: error: the following arguments are required: C:\Users\アカウント名\onsei.wav, C:\Users\アカウント名\noise.wav, --snr　といったエラーが出てしまうのですが、、、このエラーを見ると音声ファイルとノイズファイルとsnrに問題があるのでしょうか

Comment: それは別問題なので別質問として投稿してください。